# One spark task shuffle write is very slow

Tags: apache-spark

The follow picture is for the spark sql union.

One of the task shuffle write is much slower than others.

And I'm sure every task input size is very close.

Every time the task index 205 is slower than others.

And when I retry the sql, the task index 205 is very slow too.

I'm wonder what can make one task shuffle write is so slow with same input size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use repartition(number-of-partitions) to increase parallelism. This will help split the load across more partitions.

Also, if your data is not too big then consider reducing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions default value from 200 to somewhere 20 or may be 10.

Hope this will help !

Comment: I think it is not work for slow shuffle write task. Just one task is very slow